# How can I access the variables created by the init method of my inherited class?

Tags: oop, inheritance, flutter, dart, extends

I am creating an app using Flutter with Dart, and I want to create a base class for the app's config. Then, when creating a new screen, I want to create a class `ScreenConfig extends BaseConfig` and add the specific config for that screen on top of the base config. I am doing this to remove the boilerplate of having to fetch the MediaQueryData , and then set the appropriate dimensions each time when I am creating a new screen config.

**Base class**

```
class BaseConfig {
  double screenWidth;
  double screenHeight;

  double statusBarHeight;
  double navigationBarHeight;

  /// [safeScreenHeight] is the height of the device screen when
  /// the height of the statusbar and navigationbar is subtracted
  double safeScreenHeight;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenHeight = mediaQuery.size.height;
    screenWidth = mediaQuery.size.width;

    statusBarHeight = mediaQuery.padding.top;
    navigationBarHeight = kBottomNavigationBarHeight;

    safeScreenHeight = screenHeight - (statusBarHeight + navigationBarHeight);
  }
}
```

**Class that extends the base class**

```
class LoginScreenConfig extends BaseConfig {

  static Size busAnimation;
  static Size logo;
  static Size logoText;
  static Size upperLoginButton;
  static Size upperRegisterButton;
  static Size textFormField;
  static Size submitButton;

  static Size mainContainer;
  static Size yellowContainer;
  static Size greyContainer;
}

@override
void init(BuildContext context) {
  super.init(context);
}
```

I now want to ( inside `LoginScreenConfig.init()`) for example set `busAnimation` to be `Size(screenWidth * 0.5, safeScreenHeight * 0.3)`. But when I try to access `super.init()` to set the variables in the base class, I get the error `Invalid context for 'super' invocation.` I can't even access any fields of the parent class by simply writing `super.field`. What am I missing here?

**BTW:** Any suggestions for how I can manage the config of the app better is highly requested (still learning)!

Answer (score 0):

Extend your config class from InheritedWidget so then you can call it from your Widgets using `BaseConfig.of(context).busAnimation`. Here is the example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class BaseConfig extends InheritedWidget {
  final Size busAnimation;
  final Size logo;
  final Size logoText;
  final Size upperLoginButton;
  final Size upperRegisterButton;
  final Size textFormField;
  final Size submitButton;
  final Size mainContainer;
  final Size yellowContainer;
  final Size greyContainer;

  BaseConfig({
    this.busAnimation,
    this.logo,
    this.logoText,
    this.upperLoginButton,
    this.upperRegisterButton,
    this.textFormField,
    this.submitButton,
    this.mainContainer,
    this.yellowContainer,
    this.greyContainer,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  static BaseConfig of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(BaseConfig);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}
```

Then in your main file you wrap your application with BaseConfig

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'base_config.dart';
import 'my_app.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(BaseConfig(
    busAnimation: "something",
    logo: "something else",
    logoText: "and so on",
    ...
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```